# Retrieving the latest note (by timestamp) in a single query from a 1:n table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say I have two tables, users and notes.  Let's say the schemas look like this:

```
users
id, name, field2, field3

notes
id, user_id, subject, heading, body, timestamp
```

What I want to do is select every user, and the LATEST (just 1) note posted by each user based on the timestamp to show in an overview report.

How would I go about doing this?  Please note that the DB is MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881198/how-do-i-join-to-the-latest-record-in-the-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I join to the latest record in the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881198/how-do-i-join-to-the-latest-record-in-the-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select users.name, notes.subject, notes.heading, notes.body
 from users, notes
 where users.id = notes.user_id
 and notes.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from notes where user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: I ended up using this answer.  There were a few changes I needed to make, but in the end it worked!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.id, u.name, n.id as note_id, n.subject, n.heading, n.body, n.timestamp
from users u
left outer join (
    select user_id, max(timestamp) as timestamp
    from notes
    group by user_id
) nm
left outer join notes n on nm.user_id = n.user_id and nm.timestamp = n.timestamp
```

Note that this could potentially return duplicates if the user has two notes with the exact same timestamp. I have assumed this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `notes`
ON `user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `notes`.`timestamp` = (
    SELECT MAX(`timestamp`)
    FROM `notes` AS `notes_1`
    WHERE `notes_1`.`user_id` = `notes`.`user_id`
)
```